# How do Java programs run without defining the main method?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I was looking through some Java source and noticed that the `main` method wasn't defined.

How does Java compile source code without knowing where to start?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `main` method is only used when the Java Virtual Machine is executing your code.  Code cannot be executed without a `main` method but it can still be compiled.

When compiling code, you usually specify a set of files on the command line e.g.

```
javac MyClass1.java MyClass2.java
```

The Java compiler (`javac`) examines each class you passed to it and compiles it into a .class file.

One reason Java source code may be missing a `main` method is because it is designed to be used as a library, instead of being executed.

Something you may find interesting: although the source code compiled by the Java compiler does not need a `main` method, the [source code for the Java compiler itself](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/file/ce654f4ecfd8/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/Main.java) does have a `main` method.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between running and compiling.  Java code can be compiled incrementally.  You only need a `main` somewhere to *run* the code.  Java "knows where to start" because the compiler is smart enough to arrange all the dependencies when you compile.

Indeed, if you are building a web application in some sort of standard container, your code probably won't have a `main` method.  The container does, but you just write components that plug in.

Answer (score 2):

// works only on **java 1.6** or less versions

```
public class Test{   
    // this is static block

    static{
        System.out.println("This is static block");  
    }
}
```

In Java (while running):

1. all static members are identified.
2. all variables and methods    are initialized
3. static block is executed

Comment: 'Static members are identifed' is meaningless; 'all variables ... are initialized' is false; and 'methods are initialized' is meaningless. In Java 6 and earlier, maybe later too, the given output will be followed by a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` for `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

> how does Java <s>compile</s> run your source without knowing where to
>   start?

I assume you meant run (instead of compile), since you don't need a main() to compile. In which case, an explicitly declared main() method is only one of the ways to run a program.
You can use some frameworks to execute your code. They have got the main() (talking about console applications only) and require you to declare an entry point only. This is how you run unit tests, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Every single Java class you write isn't intended to be an entry point for running, that's why.  I'd say that's the rule rather than the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can run a java program without main method, for this we will use static function

Following is the code:

```
class Vishal
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Hi look program is running without main() method");
    }
}
```

This will output *"Hi look program is running without main() method"*

Comment: Followed by a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{   
    // this is static block

    static{
        System.out.println("This is static block");  
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will run fine in JDK version 1.6 or earlier. In version 1.7 and later it is necessary to include a `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

We can compile a program without main method. Actually running a program differs from compiling it.Most of the libraries do not contain a main method. so for compiling there is no problem whether the program contains main method or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("HOLAAAA");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

//by coco
//Command line:
//java -Djava.security.manager=com.test.Test
```

Comment: Hi coco and welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a hint for your first post: Please consider adding some explanatory text of how and why this works, preferably with references to documentation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is static block but in previous version of JDK not in JDK 1.7.

```
class A3{  
  static{  
  System.out.println("static block is invoked");  
  System.exit(0);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: But I can't run this code on the IDE, no "Run" button appear when I right click the class

Answer (score 0):

This will execute without any error and without main() method

```
abstract class hello extends javafx.application.Application
{
    static 
    {
    System.out.println("without main method");
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use static block too, it can be done following way

```
public class NoMain {

    private static final int STATUS = getStatus();

    private static int getStatus() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
        System.exit(0);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

However, please note that this is for Java 6 version. This doesn't seem to work in Java 7 and above

Comment: 'Its not working in Java 7 which is said to be supported in Java 8' is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, We can Compile and Execute a java program without Main function. Instead of that we can use static block to compile and Execute the program. It is supported only for previous versions of java. But now it is not supported...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).