# Can we execute a java program without a main() method?

Tags: java

According to my knowledge we cannot execute without a main method because when your running the java program. java Virtual machine look for the main method .if JVM could not find the main method it will show you run time error Exception in thread main could not find the main class.

But I searched for many blogs and some of them are saying, yes it can be done through static blogs if there is a static block in a java program,the class loader loads all static block before java gives call to main() method!.

Is it really possible and what will be the usability of these.

Comment: Duplication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591064/how-do-java-programs-run-without-defining-the-main-method

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Now - no

---

Prior to Java 7:

Yes, sequence is as follows:

- jvm loads class
- executes static blocks
- looks for main method and invokes it

So, if there's code in a static block, it will be executed. But there's no point in doing that.

How to test that:

```
public final class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("FOO");
    }
}
```

Then if you try to run the class (either form command line with `java Test` or with an IDE), the result is:

> FOO
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Comment: This answer is only valid for "deprecated" Java versions (up to version 6).

Comment: What's with Servlets and Applets? Why should they need `main()` methods?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can compile and execute without main method by using a static block. However, after static block executes, you will get an error saying no main method found.

And latest info, you can't do this with Java 7 version. It will not execute.

```
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.exit(0); // prevents “main method not found” error
    }
}
```

But this will not execute with Java 7 version.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged **Java-ee** as well - then **YES** it is possible.

and in core java as well it is possible using [static blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

and check this [How can you run a Java program without main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421542/how-can-you-run-a-java-program-without-main-method)

**Edit:**

as already pointed out in other answers - it does not support from Java 7

Comment: I want to know particularly about core java.

Comment: added link for that - By the way it doesnt makes sense to do so - as using IDE it will not run

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `coz IDEs look for main method as that's starting point for java(core) program to run

Comment: if java is looking first for static block why the ide is going to look for main method as the ide is based on java only

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal no no IDE goes also goes to static block first - you misinterepreted me. see java part is done by java and IDE part is done by IDE - take it simply as this that - it doesnt makes sense to have a program without main (so IDE simply let it off) --  seeing OO principles and its advantages - its of no use to code all your program in static block `for ex. suppose we have to create an game then we wont be coding 100+ lines of codes in that static block - it kills the OO and also look clumsy way to complex to debug.`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal welcome :) and feel free to accept one of the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should also be able to accomplish a similar thing using the [premain method of a Java agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

> The manifest of the agent JAR file must contain the attribute Premain-Class. The value of this attribute is the name of the agent class. The agent class must implement a public static premain method similar in principle to the main application entry point. After the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has initialized, each premain method will be called in the order the agents were specified, then the real application main method will be called. Each premain method must return in order for the startup sequence to proceed.