# Why there is no "public static void main" required to start an RFT script?

Tags: java, rft

I was wondering how RFT works even though it doesn't contain any `public static void main(String[] args)` in the script. The script contains a method `public void testMain(Object[] args)` which is running the script. Can someone explain how this is happening in RFT even though there is no `public static void main`?

Answer (score 0):

A Java program has not a fixed entry point. In fact, you can call any method you want, given it is accessible. What method is called is up to the application that is making the call.

What happens is that the `java` command line tool, as stated in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html):

> The java command starts a Java application. It does this by starting
>   the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), loading the specified class, and
>   calling that class's main() method. The method must be declared public
>   and static, it must not return any value, and it must accept a String
>   array as a parameter.

This is just the `java` tool behaviour. Other tools can an do behave differently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173474/can-we-execute-a-java-program-without-a-main-method

Answer (score 0):

There is no `main()` method because you don't run the RFT script as a Java application. You actually start some part of RFT which then calls the `testMain()` method. The RFT part you start contains a `main()` method. You can compare it with JUnit test cases: you run the JUnit framework and all your annotated test methods are called. In RFT you run the RFT part and your `testMain()` method gets called.