# Running Programs outside of Main on Java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm a new CS student just starting out with Java, and currently I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE. At the moment, we aren't going over any crazy complicated programs, just basic in class projects. My problem is that when I go to create my project, I have no choice but to run it through the Main class, even though the instructions want the class name to be something specific. Also, whenever I try making a new class or running a java file I've downloaded, it still continues to run the Main class, even if I have Main closed. I have files that I created inside of VS Code (I'm aware that's not the best option, and that's why I switched to IntelliJ), and I'm unable to run them unless I create a brand new project, copy and paste the code into the Main file, and change the class name to Main.

I'm not sure if this is something inside of Java, IntelliJ, or just me not understanding how everything works yet, but I was hoping someone can help me out with this.

Here's an example. In the src folder, I have the package folder and inside of this is the Main java file along with a separate file that I'm trying to run. Main is also empty.

```
package com.ethan;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercise02_19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter 3 points
        System.out.println("Enter the 3 points for a triangle: ");

        //Point A
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        //Point B
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        //Point C
        double x3 = input.nextDouble();
        double y3 = input.nextDouble();


        //Find the sides and area

        double side1 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        double side2 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y1 - y3));
        double side3 = Math.sqrt((x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2) + (y3 - y2) * (y3 - y2));

        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));

        System.out.println("The area of the triangle is: " + area);

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: show the code you were trying to run, both in Main and other classes you have in your project.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173474/can-we-execute-a-java-program-without-a-main-method

Comment: I've attached a photo. Thanks.

Comment: Insert code and mark it as code. We can not copy pictures into IDEs. Do you have another main method in main class...? If so, delete it.

Comment: Done.

Inside of the source folder, I have my package folder and inside of that I have Main.java and Exercise02_19.java.

I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: The main method in class Exercise02_19 is fine. If it starts somewhere else I guess you have another main method in Main class. Not sure what happens then. Check your Main class. If there is a main method, comment it out and run again.

Answer (score 2):

It does not depend on the classes name but on the main method which is the entry point for code execution.

This method must be defined inside a class and looks exactly like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
// code goes here
}
```

Make sure this method exists only once in your application.

To create this method fast in IntelliJ type `psvm` and then tab.

The name of the class you use to invoke the JVM determines which main method is called when you define more than one main method.

Comment: Here's an example of part of one of my files. I have this file and the empty Main file in the same location.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise02_19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter 3 points
        System.out.println("Enter the 3 points for a triangle: ");

        //Point A
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

    }
}

Comment: @efan Post additional information as part of your question by editting it, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Having your files open on an editor or on an IDEA does not mean that they are closed or open for running. They are just open to modification.

In order to run a Java program, **you need a main method** (unless you are using a framework which in that case it is hidden from you). Everything runs through main, so if you want to use a custom class you have to call it through main.

The `main` method looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     // your code
}
```

You can run the program either by using the IDEA, by setting the JDK or by compiling it with `javac` and then running the `.class` file with `java` command. There are plenty of articles on how to run your program through CLI. I would recommend using the CLI at first in order to understand what's going on JVM behind the scenes.

Comment: This is the beginning of one of my exercises. This class and the Main class are in the same file location.

public class Exercise02_19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          //all the code
}

Comment: There is no `Main class`, the only requirement for a java application is a `main method`. So your class can be named whatever you want.

Comment: Is there a way I can set the "Exercise02_19" class as the main class? The code I turn in has to be exactly how I have it, but when I run it, it just runs the Main.java file even if I have it closed.

Answer (score 1):

@efan - Alexis Pavlidis is correct.

To elaborate:

1. In Java, every "program" consists of one or more "[classes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classes-objects-java/)".  In your example, the class happens to be called `Exercise02_19`.
2. Every program must "start somewhere".  This is called an [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point).
3. In Java, the entry point is a [method](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Methods/Lesson1.htm) with the signature `public static void main(String[] args)`.
4. In Java, *unlike* many other languages, each class may have its own `main()`.  You must choose *which* entry point at runtime.  With your IDE, or with command line arguments.

   In your case, you choose the `main()` method in class `Exercise02_19`.
5. As Alexis Pavlidis said:

   > There is no Main class, the only requirement for a java application is
   >   a main method. So your class can be named whatever you want.

Answer (score -3):

A java program will **always** start in the `main()` method. You can imagine it as your entry point.

If you want to create separate classes, you must call them from your main method. Here is an example:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTestClass myInstanceOfIt = new MyTestClass();
        myInstanceOfIt.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**MyTestClass.java**

```
public class MyTestClass {

    public void doSomething() {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not always start in the Main class, but in the main method. You can declare a main method in any class.

Comment: @Tiberiu Probably because you named your class `Main` so it did not seem like a typo, and also for the fact it is just wrong still.  You do _not_ need to call classes from the main method to use them.