# is it possible to run a program by using a class without main( )

Tags: java

[image]    I've read somewhere Your Java program executing on the JVM will always begin it's execution with the main method.
but when i compile below program on **bluej** it successfully compile without any error.

```
import java.util.*;
class Calculate
{
      int m,n,s,d;//Data members
     void inputdata()
     {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("enter two numbers");
         m  = sc.nextInt();
         n = sc.nextInt();
     }
     void calculation()
     {
         s = m+n;
         d = m-d;
     }
     void outputdata()
     {
         System.out.println("sum of two  numbers:"+s);
         System.out.println("difference of two numbers:"+d);
     }
    
}
```

Please tell me in below program there is not main method so how does it compile successfully on BLUEJ? we need to create a main function where the control would be transfered when your application is first run. Otherwise the JVM won't find a function to transfer the control and your app would not run.
[image: program without main method successfully compiled]

Comment: In java, main() method is like a door from where execution starts.

Comment: Note: There is concept of blocks that run before main() method at the time of class loading but this all happens at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we execute a java program without a main() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173474/can-we-execute-a-java-program-without-a-main-method)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15173828/4957929 Check this answer.

Comment: please see second image

Comment: The second image is just a class you can use that in main() there is no problem in compiling the class. It's not mandatory for all class to have a main()

Comment: @AgentP: but sir in second image we explicit create object and call method without main( ) so it true in bluej IDE or GUI we can explicitly call method?

Comment: Under the hood, the BlueJ IDE will create a class with main() I guess because main() is the starting point of every program

Comment: under the hood means?

Comment: "under the hood" basically means "underlying implementation".

Answer (score 6):

You can compile a class without a "main" method because that is 100% valid Java.

You just can't use that class as the entry point of your application. But another application could build upon your class.

Compilation and execution are two different things and it's important to understand that.

Comment: but sir in second image we explicit create object and call non static method without main( ) so it true in bluej IDE we can explicitly call method?

Comment: I haven't used BlueJ in a while (11 years?) but IIRC, yes, you can do that in BlueJ. BlueJ is itself a Java program running in a JVM, thus it can just instantiate your class and call functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is the entry point to your program meaning any time you run your program its execution begins from the main method. So shortly no that cant happen.[Introduction to java.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_intro.asp)

Comment: Well, it can't happen unless you write an Eclipse plugin, a Minecraft mod, a Java EE app running in a servlet container, or a variety of other situations.