# I have this simple stock transaction program to compute gains or losses and nothing is being displayed when I run the program

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

The purpose of the program is to compute the gains and or losses in a simple stock market transaction and by the end the following information is needed to be displayed; number of shares, amount of purchase, amount of sell, transaction fee paid, and net profit. Here is the code that I have written thus far:

```
public class StockTransaction {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String name;
        int numberShares;
        double buyPrice,sellPrice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What's your name?");
        name=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many shares bought?");
        numberShares=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Buy price?");
        buyPrice=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Sale price?");
        sellPrice=input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        System.out.println(name + "here is the information of your stock transactions:");
        System.out.println("Number of shares:" + numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of purchase:" + buyPrice*numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of sell:" + sellPrice*numberShares);
        System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + 15 + 15);
        System.out.println("Net profit:" + (sellPrice*numberShares-buyPrice));
    }
}
```

Comment: @raffian You might want to undo that edit, he's running code as a static initializer block which might have something to do with the problem.

Comment: Change the curly braces in your code to look like the question now reads post-edit and see if it runs.

Comment: @par good catch, but was it a static init block? NES edited since my edit

Comment: See this answer for a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15755869/545127

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421618/545127

Comment: It's an instance initializer (non-static).  I hit refresh on your edit before I'd had a chance to really look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In your class, you are seeing a side effect of having too many curly braces.  To simplify, your code looks like this:

```
class StockTransaction {

    public static main() {
        // this is the content of the main() function
    }

    {
        // this is where your code is.
    }

}
```

In Java, a block of curly-braced code outside of any method acts as an instance initializer.  What this means is that when you explicitly create an object, for example with this code:

```
new StockTransaction();
```

the code inside the instance initializer will be run in addition to any constructor.  This is a convenient way to have some initialization code run no matter what constructor the user chooses to create the object with.

You will notice however that before the `main()` function is the keyword `static`.  `static` tells the compiler that the method can be called without an instance of the object.  It belongs to the `StockTransaction` class rather than to a particular instance of the class.

When your program starts, `main()` is called *without* an instance of your `StockTransaction` class.  Because there is no instance to initialize, there is no reason for your code to be called.

All of this unfortunately is what I would consider more advanced Java usage, so if it doesn't make a lot of sense now don't worry... it will later as you gain more experience with the language.

In the meantime, all you need to do to get your program to run is to move your code into the `main()` function and get rid of those extraneous curly braces.  It should look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockTransaction
{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String name;
        int numberShares;
        double buyPrice,sellPrice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What's your name?");
        name=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many shares bought?");
        numberShares=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Buy price?");
        buyPrice=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Sale price?");
        sellPrice=input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        System.out.println(name + "here is the information of your stock transactions:");
        System.out.println("Number of shares:" + numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of purchase:" + buyPrice*numberShares);
        System.out.println("Amount of sell:" + sellPrice*numberShares);
        System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + 15 + 15);
        System.out.println("Net profit:" + (sellPrice*numberShares-buyPrice));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks fine to me ( couple minor output issues )

```
What's your name?Dave
How many shares bought?1000
Buy price?10
Sale price?5

Davehere is the information of your stock transactions:
Number of shares:1000
Amount of purchase:10000.0
Amount of sell:5000.0
Transaction fee paid:1515
Net profit:4990.0
```

insert space after users name
when adding numbers together and concatenating with strings, you need parentheses around the numbers.

change this:

```
 System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + 15 + 15);
```

to:

```
 System.out.println("Transaction fee paid:" + (15 + 15));
```

also look into the line about "Net profit", it has a bug too

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?