# Can we execute a program without main() method?

Tags: java

Can we execute a program without main method and how in java tell me any example. have you done that kind of example.

Comment: well that can be done partial means u need to have static method and u can execute it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Java programs run without defining the main method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591064/how-do-java-programs-run-without-defining-the-main-method)

Comment: Well you can run parts of your code with unit-tests, like with jUnit etc. if that's what you mean.

Comment: This is possible by using static block till java 6 but from java 7 it is not possible by using static block.

Comment: You may try using `Applet`

Comment: Applets and servlets and web-apps are executed without `main()` methods, and no doubt there are other examples.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible:

```
public class MyClass {
    static {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // whatever you like
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r)
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Now you run java passing this class to the command. Java loads the class before attempting to run its main (which doesn't exist), but in loading the class, it fires the static block, which halts until the thread finishes.

If the thread finishes without exiting, java will complain there's no main method, but by that time the thread could have run anything for any duration.

You'll have to catch some exceptions in there, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestWithoutMain {   

    // static block executes first

    static{
        System.out.println("Program without main");  
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

> **Note** : This works well in JDK1.7 old versions(build 1.7.0-ea-b19)
>
> from jdk 1.7(build1.7.0-ea-b85),It gives run time Exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sequence is as follows:

1. jvm loads class
2. executes static blocks
3. looks for main method and invokes it

So, if there's code in a static block, it will be executed. But there's no point in doing that.

How to test that:

```
public final class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("FOO");
    }
}
```

Then if you try to run the class (either form command line with java Test or with an IDE), the result is:

Error will be this.

```
FOO
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

and ans is that no you can not execute program without main method but the thing is that u can use it either way means partial.

and how ever you can achieve by using static block like this.

```
static{
        System.out.println("Program without main executing into the environment.");  
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 9 and beyond you can use [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm) to execute Java code without requiring a main method. Not suitable for a stand alone application, but great for quickly testing your code and prototyping changes.

Answer (score -1):

Unless its is web application, I don't think that is possible for any stand alone application which is being self executable, the Runtime should know the entry point, The runtime design such a way that main method is an entry point.