# Keeping track of JButtons generated in a for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a Java tic-tac-toe game but I'm having trouble keeping track of my JButtons because I'm using a for loop to create 9 buttons:

```
for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){           
    button[i] = new JButton();
    button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
    frame.add(button[i]);
    button[i].addActionListener(this);
}
```

I want to check if my button text matches (in rows/columns/diagonal) and if so, display that you win.

Here is all my code:

```
public class TicTacToe extends Board implements ActionListener{
    JButton button[] = new JButton[9];
    boolean win = false;
    int count = 0;
    String letter = "";

    public TicTacToe(){
        //create + add JButtons to JFrame
        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
            frame.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            if(i%2 == 0){
                letter = "X";
            }else{
                letter = "O";
            }

            if(e.getSource() == button[i]){
                button[i].setText(letter);
                button[i].setEnabled(false);
                count = i+1;
            }

            //check win
            if(){             //<---------------NEED HELP HERE. THANK YOU
                win = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU WIN");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I keep track of dynamically created JButtons?

Comment: there's no question in your question.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "keep track" of them. Do you mean add separate listeners?

Comment: By "keep track" I mean that if button1 text == button2 text == button3 text then win=true. Since I don't have different names for each button I cant do that.

Comment: do you just want to check those three buttons only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The win conditions for tic tac toe are:

```
X - -    - X -    - - X
X - - or - X - or - - X
X - -    - X -    - - X

private boolean colWinner() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String mark = button[i].getText();
    if (mark.equals(button[i+3].getText()) &&
        mark.equals(button[i+6].getText()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

or

```
X X X    - - -    - - -
- - - or X X X or - - -
- - -    - - -    X X X

private boolean rowWinner() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String mark = button[3*i].getText();
    if (mark.equals(button[3*i+1].getText()) &&
        mark.equals(button[3*i+2].getText()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

or

```
X - -    - - X
- X - or - X -
- - X    X - -

private boolean diagWinner() {
  String mark = button[4].getText();
  return 
    (mark.equals(button[0].getText()) && mark.equals(button[8].getText()) ||
    (mark.equals(button[2].getText()) && mark.equals(button[6].getText());
}
```

This naive approach checks all possible win conditions, which isn't really necessary if you are checking for wins after each turn. You only need to check the conditions for:

1. the row the new mark was made
2. the col the new mark was made
3. one diagonal if the mark is in a corner or both diagonals if the mark is in the center.

I'll leave it to you to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

First I will answer your question, but judging by your code (or lack thereof), I will then address some other things I think you should be aware of as a Java programmer working with Graphical User Interfaces (GUIs) and Java Swing.

---

## Part 1: The Answer

There are **two approaches** I can think of to solve this.

The following code uses a two-dimensional array of pieces to represent the 3x3 board of JButtons (note sure why you don't use a 2D array, actually very confused on why you don't). Additionally, it assumed that the text of all JButtons is initially set to "." since this is much easier than checking if the text is one of 9 different string numbers.

### Approach A: Static Cases

Since the board is so small, it's feasible to simply check for each of the cases where a player would win the tic tac toe game and verify if one of them is true. The following graphic illustrates the **eight cases** that result in a winning outcome for a player.

Note that "O" can just as easily be substituted for "X" below, the important thing is that each one belongs to the same player. Additionally, any "." marks are just placeholders, as it doesn't matter whether this actually represents "X," "O," or "null" on the board.

[image: Cases where player wins tic tac toe game]

```
// Case 1

// if each location across the top row is not empty
if (board[0][0].getText() != "." && board[0][1].getText() != "." && board[0][2].getText() != ".") {

        // if each location has the same text
        if (board[0][0].getText() == board[0][1].getText() && 
            board[0][0].getText() == board[0][2].getText()) {

            // if the player is X then X is winner, else player is O and O is winner
            if (board[0][0].player() == Player.X)
                return Status.X_WINNER;
            else if (board[0][0].player() == Player.O)
                return Status.O_WINNER;
        }
 }
```

This can then be repeated seven times to achieve our goal. However, this is a lot of repetitive code, and clever programmers will attempt to avoid this when possible.

But, there's also the case of a **tie** or **"cat's game"** in tic tac toe, and how do we address this? Well, if there are no winning cases present *AND* the board is full of pieces, then we have a stalemate.

### Approach B: Dynamic Checking

I'll admit, this method is a behemoth and I'm sure it could use some smart refactoring, but it's functional and solves the problem dynamically. There are many conditionals to try and make the algorithm more efficient by only continuing when absolutely necessary.

Note that I check the surrounding neighbors of a piece, which is critical for properly checking if a diagonal has won the game.

```
// track if game won
boolean won = false;

        // constant for board width and height
        int BOARD_SIZE = 3;

        // track pieces on board
        int numPieces = 0;

        // track who won
        String winner = "";

        // loop through the board first time
        for (int row1 = 0; row1 < board.length; row1++) {
            for (int col1 = 0; col1 < board.length; col1++) {

                // if piece exists here
                if (board[row1][col1].getText() != ".") {

                    // increment number of pieces on board
                    numPieces++;

                    // check pieces around first piece
                    for (int row2 = row1 - 1; row2 <= row1 + 1; row2++) {
                        for (int col2 = col1 - 1; col2 <= col1 + 1; col2++) {

                            // ensure within bounds of board
                            if ((row2 >= 0 && row2 < BOARD_SIZE) && (col2 >= 0 && col2 < BOARD_SIZE)) {

                                // ignore checking with first piece (itself)
                                if (board[row2][col2] != board[row1][col1]) {

                                    // if second piece equal to first piece
                                    if (board[row2][col2].getText() == board[row1][col1].getText()) {

                                        // check pieces around second piece
                                        for (int row3 = row2 - 1; row3 <= row2 + 1; row3++) {
                                            for (int col3 = col2 - 1; col3 <= col2 + 1; col3++) {

                                                // ensure within bounds of board
                                                if ((row3 >= 0 && row3 < BOARD_SIZE) && (col3 >= 0 && col3 < BOARD_SIZE)) {

                                                    // ignore checking pieces we already have
                                                    if (board[row3][col3] != board[row2][col2] && board[row3][col3] != board[row1][col1]) {

                                                        // if third piece equal to first piece (and so also equal to second)
                                                        if (board[row3][col3].getText() == board[row1][col1].getText()) {

                                                            // if three pieces are all on same row
                                                            if (row1 == row2 && row1 == row3) {
                                                                if (board[row1][col1].getText() == "X")
                                                                    winner = "X";
                                                                else
                                                                    winner = "O";
                                                                won = true;
                                                                break;
                                                            }

                                                            // else if three pieces are all on same column
                                                            else if (col1 == col2 && col1 == col3) {
                                                                if (board[row1][col1].getText() == "X")
                                                                    winner = "X";
                                                                else
                                                                    winner = "O";
                                                                won = true;
                                                                break;
                                                            }

                                                            // else if three pieces are all on different rows and columns (winning diagonal)
                                                            else if ((row1 != row2 && row1 != row3 && row2 != row3) && (col1 != col2 && col1 != col3 && col2 != col3)) {
                                                                if (board[row1][col1].getText() == "X")
                                                                    winner = "X";
                                                                else
                                                                    winner = "O";
                                                                won = true;
                                                                break;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (winner == "X") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X wins");
        }
        else if (winner == "O") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O wins");
        }

        // if board is full and hasn't resulted in any winners
        if (!won && numPieces == BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cats game");
```

Of course, less lines of code do not necessarily guarantee better performance, as we are again lucky that this is such a small board. Looping through multiple times (i.e. brute force approach) like this on a large board would spell disastrous run times, so this is another design choice to consider.

---

## Part 2: Going Further

I don't think this can really be all your code, as your provided code can't be executed [without a main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591064/how-do-java-programs-run-without-defining-the-main-method).

Additionally, if you're extending a "Board" class, you must have written your own since Java doesn't come with such a class.

Here are some things you should be aware of as a Java Swing GUI programmer.

### A. Java Swing

You don't seem to have a strong grasp on Java Swing, so here's [an introductory tutorial](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/lect/l7/) to start you off.

### B. Layout Managers

Layout managers can be your friend but also your enemy when trying to configure your GUI layout. Here's [a good resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your exploration.

### C. Model-View-Controller (MVC)

Decoupling dependencies is key to future management of large code bases. MVC is a popular software architectural pattern that helps reduce dependencies when dealing with user interfaces. [Check this out](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/rkline/java/mvc-design.html).

### D. My Implementation

You inspired me to work on my own Java Swing implementation of tic-tac-toe. [Here it is](https://bitbucket.org/michaelbaldwin/tic-tac-toe/src)!

---

Cheers and happy coding!