# JAVA--- Compiler and Runtime errors. Class main

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

```
/* Airport class
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/


public class Airport
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
// 1. ***** Define the instance variables  *****
// airportCode is a String
// gates is an integer
// Part 1 student code starts here:


    private String airportCode;
    private int gates;


// Part 1 student code ends here.

// 2. ***** Write this method *****
// Default constructor:
// method name: Airport
// return value:  none
// parameters: none
// function: sets the airportCode to an empty String
// Part 2 student code starts here:
    public Airport()
    {
        airportCode = "";
    }


// Part 2 student code ends here.

// 3. ***** Write this method *****
// Overloaded constructor:
// method name: Airport
// return value: none
// parameters:  a String startAirportCode and an int startGates
// function:
//      calls the the setAirportCode method,
//                   passing startAirportCode parameter;
//      calls the setGates method, passing the startGates parameter
// Part 3 student code starts here:
    public Airport(String startAirportCode, int startGates)
    {
        setAirportCode(startAirportCode);
        setGates(startGates);

    }

// Part 3 student code ends here.

// 4. ***** Write this method *****
// Accessor method for the airportCode instance variable
// method name: getAirportCode
// return value: String
// parameters: none
// function: returns airportCode
// Part 4 student code starts here:
    public String getAirportCode()
    {
        return airportCode;
    }


// Part 4 student code ends here.

// 5. ***** Write this method *****
// Accessor method for the gates instance variable
// method name: getGates
// return value: int
// parameters: none
// function: returns gates
// Part 5 student code starts here:
    public int getGates()
    {
        return gates;
    }


// Part 5 student code ends here.

// 6. ***** Write this method *****
// Mutator method for the airportCode instance variable
// method name: setAirportCode
// return value: void
// parameters: String newAirportCode
// function: assigns airportCode the value of the
//                    newAirportCode parameter
// Part 6 student code starts here:
    public void setAirportCode(String newAirportCode)
    {
      airportCode = newAirportCode;
    }


// Part 6 student code ends here.

// 7. ***** Write this method *****
// Mutator method for the gates instance variable
// method name: setGates
// return value:  void
// parameters: int newGates
// function: validates the newGates parameter.
//   if newGates is greater than or equal to 0,
//       sets gates to newGates;
//       otherwise, prints an error message to System.err
//        and does not change value of gates
// Part 7 student code starts here:
    public void setGates(int newGates)
    {
        if (newGates >= 0)
        gates = newGates;
    else
        {
            System.err.println("Gates must be at least 0.");
            System.err.println("Value of gates unchanged.");
            return;
        }





    /*public void setGates(int newGates)
    {
        newGates = gates;
    }

*/
// Part 7 student code ends here.

    enter code here

}  // end of Airport class definition
}
```

//The code in the book does not contain the public static void main(String[] args). I added it anyway once I searched the site and it said that you cannot do that with recent java updates. Without the main statement, I got it to compile successfully, but had a runtime error that said "main method not found in airport class". I added it and got some compiler errors. I played with the curly braces, and eventually broke it... now I can't figure out why I'm getting like, 23 comp errors.

I'm coding in textpad with Java external tools. 
It works with the main class and StackFlow's method, but not without the main class- still says it can't find the class. I removed the "private" from the instance variables. It compiles successfully without it, but still has the aforementioned runtime error. 
This file doesn't really run, but it is to be used with another framework coded for me. This is just part 1; the foundation for part 2.

For whoever else inquires after me, I do believe it "works only on java 1.6 or less versions"
[How do Java programs run without defining the main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591064/how-do-java-programs-run-without-defining-the-main-method)

Thanks again everyone for your help. This site is AWESOME!

Comment: What's is supposed to do in main() ?

Comment: it seems to me you are declaring methods in methods. This code won't compile, let alone run

Answer (score 1):

This should unbreak (but not fix) this:

```
public class Airport
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.println("Running. But what do I have to do?");
} //CLOSE THAT MAIN <- need to close that method.

[... all you code ...]

}  // end of Airport class definition
//Remove this. Class already ended. }
```

From there on you should do two things: Find out what's supposed to happen in main() and install an IDE with syntax highlighting and stuff like eclipse. That will point out these kinds of errors for you.

Comment: Ha! I have textpad. Totally should have noted that! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    private String airportCode;
    private int gates;
 }
```

Your variables go outside main function or declare them as local.
You also need to close out main before you start an other functions.

You correct code would look like:

```
/* Airport class
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/


public class Airport
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
// 1. ***** Define the instance variables  *****
// airportCode is a String
// gates is an integer
// Part 1 student code starts here:
    private String airportCode;
    private int gates;


// Part 1 student code ends here.

// 2. ***** Write this method *****
// Default constructor:
// method name: Airport
// return value:  none
// parameters: none
// function: sets the airportCode to an empty String
// Part 2 student code starts here:
    public Airport()
    {
        airportCode = "";
    }


// Part 2 student code ends here.

// 3. ***** Write this method *****
// Overloaded constructor:
// method name: Airport
// return value: none
// parameters:  a String startAirportCode and an int startGates
// function:
//      calls the the setAirportCode method,
//                   passing startAirportCode parameter;
//      calls the setGates method, passing the startGates parameter
// Part 3 student code starts here:
    public Airport(String startAirportCode, int startGates)
    {
        setAirportCode(startAirportCode);
        setGates(startGates);

    }

// Part 3 student code ends here.

// 4. ***** Write this method *****
// Accessor method for the airportCode instance variable
// method name: getAirportCode
// return value: String
// parameters: none
// function: returns airportCode
// Part 4 student code starts here:
    public String getAirportCode()
    {
        return airportCode;
    }


// Part 4 student code ends here.

// 5. ***** Write this method *****
// Accessor method for the gates instance variable
// method name: getGates
// return value: int
// parameters: none
// function: returns gates
// Part 5 student code starts here:
    public int getGates()
    {
        return gates;
    }


// Part 5 student code ends here.

// 6. ***** Write this method *****
// Mutator method for the airportCode instance variable
// method name: setAirportCode
// return value: void
// parameters: String newAirportCode
// function: assigns airportCode the value of the
//                    newAirportCode parameter
// Part 6 student code starts here:
    public void setAirportCode(String newAirportCode)
    {
      airportCode = newAirportCode;
    }


// Part 6 student code ends here.

// 7. ***** Write this method *****
// Mutator method for the gates instance variable
// method name: setGates
// return value:  void
// parameters: int newGates
// function: validates the newGates parameter.
//   if newGates is greater than or equal to 0,
//       sets gates to newGates;
//       otherwise, prints an error message to System.err
//        and does not change value of gates
// Part 7 student code starts here:
    public void setGates(int newGates)
    {
        if (newGates >= 0)
        gates = newGates;
    else
        {
            System.err.println("Gates must be at least 0.");
            System.err.println("Value of gates unchanged.");
            return;
        }





    /*public void setGates(int newGates)
    {
        newGates = gates;
    }

*/
// Part 7 student code ends here.

    enter code here

}
```

// end of Airport class definition
    }

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that, but then I get this.  Bulldogs\1.CIS210\week7\Airport.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
  private String airportCode;
  ^
Downloads\New folder\GMC Bulldogs\1.CIS210\week7\Airport.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
  private int gates;
  ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: This!! Thanks so much!! It works now. I still don't understand why the framework did not prompt me to add the main, or if it really is necessary (another commenter said it isn't), but I totally learned something new!!

Comment: Main can be a part of any class where you want to start you execution. Hence the framework doesn't force you to add it to a particular class . Glad this helped. do forget to close out the question by marking it as an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This may help!!! As some one above said it,

> Your variables go outside main function or declare them as local. You also need to close out main before you start an other functions.

```
public class Airport
{  
String airportCode;
int gates;

public Airport()
{
    airportCode = "";
}

public Airport(String startAirportCode, int startGates)
{
    setAirportCode(startAirportCode);
    setGates(startGates);

}

public String getAirportCode()
{
    return airportCode;
}


public int getGates()
{
    return gates;
}


public void setAirportCode(String newAirportCode)
{
  airportCode = newAirportCode;
}

public void setGates(int newGates)
{
    if (newGates >= 0)
    gates = newGates;
else
    {
        System.err.println("Gates must be at least 0.");
        System.err.println("Value of gates unchanged.");
        return;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Airport r = new Airport("Hello", 1);
    r.setAirportCode("Abcd");
    System.out.println("" + r.getAirportCode());
    r.setGates(3);
    System.out.println("" + r.getGates());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a main method.  If you remove these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
```

and comment out this line at the bottom:

```
enter code here
```

It should compile: `javac Airport.java`.  This Airport object sounds like something that you don't run... just build it and it will behave like an airport.  I'm guessing that later in the lesson you are going to make something that uses the Airport... like an AirportSimulator.java.  It might have a main method and look something like this:

```
public class AirportSimulator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AirportSimulator airsim = new AirportSimulator();
        airsim.simulate();
    }

    public void simulate()
    {
        Airport air = new Airport();
        System.out.println("Setting gates to 1");
        air.setGates(1);
        System.out.println(String.format("Gates set to %d", air.getGates());
        System.out.println("Setting airport code to IAD");
        air.setAirportCode("IAD");
        System.out.println(String.format("Airport code is %s", air.getAirportCode());
    }
}
```

My point is that a Simulator is like a verb and makes more sense that you would run it with a main, while an Airport is like a noun.